# Can I manually select the used theme in bqplot?

Tags: python, bqplot

I'm manually setting up a bqplot canvas:

```py
import bqplot as bq

ys = bq.LinearScale()
xs = bq.DateScale()
xax = bq.Axis(scale=self.xs, label="Date", grid_lines="solid")
yax = bq.Axis(scale=self.ys, label="NDVI", orientation="vertical", grid_lines="solid")
ndvi_chart = bq.Figure(axes=[xax, yax], title = "NDVI evolution")
```

Problem, the rest of my dashboard is piloted by the ipyvuetify `theme` boolean trait. SO in the current implementation, my app and my plot can be out of sync.

[image]

Is there a way to manually change the theme of the bqplot figure object ?